# Xamarin TabbedPage without shadow on android

Tags: xaml, xamarin, tabbedpage

I created a really simple TabbedPage on my project and i set the BarBackground to the same color of the other pages but the bar has a shadow that i want to remove but i don't know how to do it. I tried to set the BarBackground to "Transparent" but doesn't work or i just don't know how to set properly. I know on IOS there's a way but i couldn't find on android.

My TabbedPage:

```
<local:Hub IconImageSource="checklist.png"></local:Hub>
<local:Home IconImageSource="home.png"></local:Home>
<local:ChartView IconImageSource="charthistogram.png"></local:ChartView>
```

[image]

Comment: what "shadow" are you talking about?  I see an incredibly faint line above the tab icons, is that what you mean?  It's often helpful to annotate your screenshots to point specifically to what you're talking about to eliminate confusion

Comment: @Jason sorry about the confusion on the screenshot, yes i'm talking about this faint line above the tab icons.

Comment: You might be able to do this with a custom renderer. You may refer to this link, which may be helpful to you:"https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/contentpage".